# How to get a character from a string - getting wrong character and wrong length of string

Tags: python, string, unicode

Below python gives wrong length of string and wrong character.
Does anybody here have any idea?

```
>>> w ='lòng'
>>> w 
'lòng'
>>> print (w)
lòng
>>> len(w)
5
>>> for ch in w:
...     print (ch + "-") 
... 
l- 
o- 
- 
n- 
g- 
>>>
```

Comment: length should be 4 and w[1] should be 'ò'.  Javascript and visual basic work but not python

Comment: Yours is a unicode string. The python `len()` method for strings counts __code points__. The second character uses 2 code points.

Comment: @rdas the question you identified as a duplicate is actually opposite of the problem described here.

Comment: The duplicate target doesn't explain this particular case particularly well, IMO, but take a look at the Unicode How-to section on [comparing strings](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#comparing-strings) for an explanation of how unicode may compose an accented character from two separate characters.

Comment: @CommandMe I tested `len('lòng')` in both Python 3.7 and 3.8 on MacOS, and it is 4, not 5. The question cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @CommandMe This issue could be reproduced only with Python 2.7, but people shouldn't be using Python 2.7 anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that in unicode some characters may be composed of combinations of other characters.  In this case, 'lòng' includes lower case 'o' and a grave accent as separate characters.

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> w ='lòng'
>>> for c in w:
...     print(ud.name(c))
... 
LATIN SMALL LETTER L
LATIN SMALL LETTER O
COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT
LATIN SMALL LETTER N
LATIN SMALL LETTER G
```

This is a *decomposed* unicode string, because the accented 'o' is decomposed into two characters.  The [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) module provides the [normalize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) function to convert between decomposed and *composed* forms:

```
>>> for c in ud.normalize('NFC', w):
...     print(ud.name(c))
... 
LATIN SMALL LETTER L
LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH GRAVE
LATIN SMALL LETTER N
LATIN SMALL LETTER G
```

If you want to know whether a string is normalised to a particular form, but don't want to actually normalise it, and are using Python 3.8+, the more efficient [unicodedata.is_normalized](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.is_normalized) function can be used (*credit to user Acumenus*):

```
>>> ud.is_normalized('NFC', w)
False
>>> ud.is_normalized('NFD', w)
True
```

The [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) in the Python documentation includes a section on [comparing strings](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#comparing-strings) which discusses this in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode allows a lot of flexibility on encoding a character.  In this case, the `ò` is actually made up of **2** Unicode code points, one for the base character `o` and one for the accent mark.  Unicode also has a character that represents both at the same time, and it doesn't care which you use.  Unicode allows a lot of flexibility on encoding a character.  Python includes a package [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)that can provide a consistent representation.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> w ='lòng'
>>> len(w)
5
>>> len(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', w))
4
```

Comment: As of Python 3.8, the [`is_normalized`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.is_normalized) function also exists and [is faster](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#unicodedata) to check first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `len` function and the `in` operator are *broken* w.r.t. Unicode.

As of now, there are two answers that claim normalisation is the solution. Unfortunately, that's not true in general:

```
>>> w = 'Ꙝ̛͋ᄀᄀᄀ각ᆨᆨ❤️'
>>> len(w)
19
>>> import unicodedata
>>> len(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', w))
19
>>> # 19 is still wrong
```

To handle this task correctly, you need to operate on graphemes:

```
>>> from grapheme import graphemes
>>> w = 'Ꙝ̛͋ᄀᄀᄀ각ᆨᆨ❤️'
>>> len(list(graphemes(w)))
3
>>> # 3 is correct
>>> for g in graphemes(w):
...     print(g)
Ꙝ̛͋
ᄀᄀᄀ각ᆨᆨ
❤️
```

Also works for your `w = 'lòng'` input, correctly segments into 4 without any normalisation.

Comment: Yes, still broken in 3.8. You could have tested that yourself. They just updated some data files, of course that does not change how `len` works.

Comment: And you could have in your answer linked to the third-party package you are talking about.

Comment: I tested `len('lòng')` in both Python 3.7 and 3.8 on MacOS, and it is 4, not 5. As for your string `Ꙝ̛͋ᄀᄀᄀ각ᆨᆨ❤️`, its length was 14, not 19.

Comment: Your `lòng` differs from the `lòng` all the other participants in this thread are using. ––– The Stackexchange software sabotaged my example input. Here it is again in escaped notation so I can circumvent that bug: \N{U+0A65C}\N{U+0031B}\N{U+0034B}\N{U+00356}\N{U+00489}\N{U+01100}\N{U+01100}\N{U+01100}\N{U+0AC01}\N{U+011A8}\N{U+011A8}\N{U+1F469}\N{U+0200D}\N{U+02764}\N{U+0FE0F}\N{U+0200D}\N{U+1F48B}\N{U+0200D}\N{U+1F469}

Comment: The original issue could be reproduced by me only with Python 2.7 which is a version of Python that people shouldn't be using anymore.